# Access one instance of a jdialog from different class java

Tags: java, swing, scope, jframe, jdialog

I have a JFrame that houses my many JPanels that represent different parts of my application in which you can do certain calculations.

I have a JDialog that is created in my Main.java class (extends the JFrame) and is designed to be used as an output window (i.e. whatever calculations are performed in different JPanel classes, the result should be appended to this output windows JTextArea).

My question is, how do I access this JDialog from my other classes? I don't want to instanciate another Jdialog but use the existing window... I have getters and setters for the JDialog but I am a little lost on how to get the connection between the instance of my OutputWindow class in the Main java file and the other JPanels that house the different parts of my application.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is just provide access to an inner class from classes defined elsewhere, as long as it is public and static you should be able to it.

If you are going to have just the one instance throughout all your project you should use the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern to properly ensure this.

Comment: Thanks, I made both the TextArea in the dialog public static and the jdialog instance in my main file. Works like a charm.  THanks!